# How to reserve a RAM area to store some warm-reset-proof data?

Tags: u-boot

I have a board with ppc405, 128M RAM populated and booting with u-boot + linux 2.6.10 kernel. For some reason, I need to make sure some data can survive after warm-reset. As far as I know, u-boot have a parameter "pram=" for this, so-called "protected ram". But I don't know what to do next, shall I write a driver so that the application can access that RAM area?

Comment: [This](http://lwn.net/Articles/315943/) could be a good place to start. It is the LOGBUFFER facility. u-boot reserves/protects some memory in RAM. Linux kernel access the reserved/protected memory. The most important part is remapping the protected memory area.